# cp: invalid option -- 'o'

Tags: cp

I'm following [an installation script on GitHub](https://github.com/named-data-mobile/NFD-android/blob/master/README.md) and one of the steps is:

`cp sources/openssl/1.0.1p/Android.mk -o sources/openssl/$OPENSSL_VERSION/Android.mk`

But my terminal threw an error `cp: invalid option -- 'o'`

I checked `man cp` on my Ubuntu, and there's no option `-o`. Is this a MAC OS thing? What does `cp -o` stand for?

Comment: I'm not sure where the -o came from but I am presuming that it isn't needed and the copy is simply copying from one source destination to a source directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely remove the -o option. Btw, is $OPENSSL_VERSION set?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is set (OPENSSL_VERSION=1.0.2h)

Comment: then just remove -o, I think people at github didn't mean to put it there, really

Answer (score 9):

That's a typo. There is no implementation of `cp` that has a `-o` option on any Unix that I know of. My guess is that this option may safely be removed.

It *may* be that they meant `cp -p` (preserve mode, timestamp and ownership when used with GNU `cp` and others), or `cp -i` for interactive prompting in case the file already exists.

They are obviously using GNU `cp` though, since they intermingle operands with options. Ordinary tools usually stop parsing the command line at the first non-option, but GNU tools will try to be smart.

Comment: Anyway, `cp file -o dir` is meant to copy the `file` and `-o` files to `dir`. Only GNU (or GNU-like like busybox) `cp` would take that `-o` as an option (and only when `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment)

Comment: Possibly it was confusion with the common `curl`…`-o`.  But this is all guesswork.  Only Lei Pi can really explain.

Comment: With GNU `cp`, `cp --o` would be an abbreviation for `cp --one-file-system`. I agree with JdeBP that it is just a typo especially considering that the next section does something similar with `curl -o`. It's not any indication that they're using GNU `cp` or any other implementation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas On ubuntu `--one-file-system` option is abbreviated to `-x`

Comment: @user000001, yes, but `--o` (or `--on`, or `--one`...) would also work (note the double dash)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Ah, I missed the second dash. It's really cool that you can abbreviate long options like that, I hadn't realized it even after many years of using linux. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @user000001 If you ever write a script (or documentation), don't abbreviate the options though. It makes it unnecessarily hard to understand.